# P2p connection of users

Tags: sockets, p2p

I am newbie in Socket programming. so I don't know whether I can explain my intent. I am running a node.js socket server for direct connection of two client using android app. Here I want to make two Android(or Java application) client accessing node.js socket connect directly(not through server). If an Android client opens a server socket, is it possible for the other user to access that server socket? Although socket server tells the IP address of opposite client(open server socket and waiting connection) it is impossible to connect because it is under router. What I want to know is When two clients access my server, How can I make to clients connects directly(not through server) using socket. I will be very happy if somebody helps me.

I don't know where should I start from.

Know someone who can answer? Share a link to this question via email, Twitter, or Facebook.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do. What do you mean by "connects directly (not through server)"?

Comment: No, there is no way to do it. If the peers connect to the server then by definition they are not connected to each other.